# Processing JSON data in angular 7

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

So I'm very new to Angular, html, and Typescript...
With that said I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7w5c6IlmaA

I've got the JSON data to show in the console just fine. However at 24:12 in his video I get the same error as him, except it doesn't work.

I've tried to push the city name to the console from home.component.ts and still getting the same error.

Here's some code that may explain my stupidity, thanks!

home.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {WeatherService} from '../weather.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {


  location = {
    city: 'orlando',
    code: 'us'

  };

  weather: any;

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherService.getWeather(this.location.city, this.location.code).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);

      this.weather = result;
      // console.log(this.weather.city.name);
    });
  }

}
```

weather.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {



  apiKey = 'Promise I didn't mess this part up';
  url;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=';
  }


  getWeather(city, code) {

    return this.http.get(this.url + city + ',' + code + '&APPID=' + this.apiKey).pipe(map(result => {
      console.log(result);
    }));
  }

}
```

Comment: getWeather should return result after console.log?

Comment: If you are using the RxJS `map()` operator, you need to return the mapped data in some format, whatever format. Right now you aren't returning anything inside the body of `map()`, which will effectively pass nothing to the `subscribe()`. You don't even really need `pipe()` or `map()` in your example. You can just console.log() inside of the subscribe if really needed.

Comment: you need return result from getWeather after console log

Comment: Or not even do `map()` at all. It's unnecessary in your example. If you need to log something, you can use a side-effect operator such as [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html)

Comment: if you just want to add a log statement and not affect the content you should use the `tap` operator instead of `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from your service, you should return it as,

```
getWeather(city, code) 
      return this.http.get(this.url + city + ',' + code + '&APPID=' + this.apiKey).pipe(map(result => {
          console.log(result); 
          return result;
        }));
 }
```

Comment: You are a saint, I knew something was fishy there! Thanks so much, will accept answer as soon as it will let me. :D

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return restult after console log replace below method

```
getWeather(city, code) {

    return this.http.get(this.url + city + ',' + code + '&APPID=' + this.apiKey).pipe(map(result => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }));
  }
```

Hope this help! :)